# Throw k-side dice N times, 1 never appears, while 2 appears at least once

Tags: probability, dice, binomial-distribution

Say I throw a fair **k**-sided dice **N** times. What is the probability that the specific value **1** will never appear, while the value **2** will appear at least once?

The probability for **1** never to appear is easy: $P = \left(1-\frac{1}
{k}\right)^N$

For **2** to appear at least once: $P = 1- \left(1-\frac{1}
{k}\right)^N$

But since they are dependent (if **1** appears in a roll, **2** does not), I cannot simply multiply them. Is there any easy way to find the combined probability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Count the number of sequences directly.  The number of sequences possible is $k^N$.  The number of sequences with no $1$'s and no $2$'s is $(k-2)^N$.  The number of sequences with no $1$'s and no requirement on $2$'s is $(k-1)^N$.  So... the number of sequences with no $1$'s and at least one $2$ is...

> $(k-1)^N-(k-2)^N$

And so the probability is...

> $$\dfrac{(k-1)^N-(k-2)^N}{k^N}$$

Comment: Simple and elegant, thank you!